# camel-sql get statement from headers

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using the camel-sql component like this:

```
<to uri="sql:select * from myTable?dataSource=#java:/MySqlDS"/>
```

Now what I would like to do is retrive the sql command from a header value.
Following the documentation, I tried this:

```
<to uri="sql::#${headers.sql}?dataSource=#java:/MySqlDS"/>
```

whicht results in:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  ' 'select * from test' ' at line 1

(Please note 2 single quotes at the beginning and the end) 
using `${headers.sql}` results in:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '${headers.sql}' at line 1

**Question:** What do I have to do to prevent the double quotation and end up with valid Sql syntax?

Please note that the header value is set inside the route from the backing bean not in xml, hence I cannot do something like this...or can I? :

```
<setHeader headerName="myHeader">
  <constant>myValue</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this FAQ about *dynamic to*
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html eg use `<toD>` for the dynamic to.